# popen causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, popen

I've used popen function in my c program to execute a shell command and return the result. It works works perfectly for 90% of times but unfortunately for some reason, sometimes I get segmentation fault.

Here are the code place and gdb stacktrace:

```
FILE *fp = popen("ip route list | grep default | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '\n'", "r");
```

And the stack trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_malloc (av=0x7ffff795d760 <main_arena>, bytes=256) at malloc.c:3491
3491    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff795d760 <main_arena>, bytes=256) at malloc.c:3491
#1  0x00007ffff761dae0 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=256) at malloc.c:2893
#2  0x00007ffff760ac48 in _IO_new_popen (command=0x415128 "ip route list | grep default | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '\n'", mode=0x414fde "r") at iopopen.c:288
```

Comment: From what I see, you're doing something wrong. Calling a shell script from a [tag:c] program seems to be an indication that you are having [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), please tell us what is it that you really want to do. That said, the code you posted is not responsible for the segmentation fault, it's likely that your program is handling memory in a wrong manner, and thus causing undefined behavior. You have to post the relevant code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It still should provide a `pipe` descriptor, no? Or `NULL`.

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault inside malloc, it could be that the memory arena was already corrupted by some earlier writing using an invalid pointer.

Comment: After more testing, I agree with @IharobAlAsimi -- your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try to dig more into earlier codes. its an unfortunate that vagrind gives nothing